# An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a problem with many to many association
i have 2 entity one named user

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="DataSiteBundle\Entity\Site", mappedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *     name="id_site",
 *     referencedColumnName="id_site",
 *     nullable=false,
 *     onDelete="CASCADE"
 * )
 */
private $site;
```

and the other is named site

```
/**
 * @Groups({"site-read","site-write"})
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User" , inversedBy="site")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *     name="id_user",
 *     referencedColumnName="id_user",
 *     nullable=false,
 *     onDelete="CASCADE"
 * )
 *
 */
private $user;
```

when im trying to do `doctrine:schema:update --force`

i got this
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 121:

> An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE site_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B6096BB0F6BD1646 FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES sp_site (id) ON DELETE CASCADE':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there is  a table with an existing constraint. I think there are two solutions

If you are in dev, you can rebuild your database

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

If you are in production I think that you need to make a script to get your data, save somewhere, delete table and remake it, or create a script in sql to skip this problem

Comment: What have you tried? to drop database? If so, delete cache directory before done everything please @MajdiAllagui

Comment: cache deleted but no result

Comment: when i execute doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

i got this 

     ALTER TABLE site_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B6096BB0F6BD1646 FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES sp_site (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
     ALTER TABLE site_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B6096BB0A76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES fos_user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

Comment: (site_id) should be (id_site) and (user_id) should be(id_user)